# Add a sub menu after Run in Eclipse menu

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to add a sub menu, 'run as sample', after 'run as'. I need when I right click on a project in project explorer. and I need to give some functions in that menu item. How can I write plugin.xml for that. need to specify the class file too